# Get name of the bound method from instance of the bound method object in Python

Tags: python, methods

I have :

```
class A:
    def a():
       pass
```

After typing in the python command line:

```
Aobj = A()
aBoundMeth = getattr(Aobj, 'a')
```

My goal is to get the name of the method that **aBoundMeth** object represents. Is it possible to do it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why use `getattr` here?

Comment: I think the question is given `aboundMeth` (regardless of how it obtained its value), what is a/the name associated with the bound method object. Using `aBoundMeth = Aobj.a` would not affect the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that the name of the method is the string `'a'` (in this case), You can use the `__name__` attribute on the function object.

e.g.

```
>>> Aobj = A()
>>> aBoundMeth = getattr(Aobj, 'a')
>>> aBoundMeth.__name__
'a'
```

Note that this is the function name when it was created.  You can make more references to the same function, but the name doesn't change.  e.g.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def a(self):
...        pass
...     b = a
... 
>>> Aobj = A()
>>> Aobj.a.__name__
'a'
>>> Aobj.b.__name__
'a'
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why it's impossible to see **__name__** using **dir(aBoundMeth)**

Comment: @user1264304 - "*Note Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names*" - http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir

Comment: `dir` gets it's its info from `__dict__`.  If you actually look at a function object's `__dict__`.  If you look at the function object's dict, it is empty -- So python must be doing some sort of special `__getattr__` magic within the interpreter to give you the name.